# Use/Need of Visitor Pattern in prog. lang. that support class extensions or open classes

Tags: visitor-pattern

I'm confronted with the following software design question: 
Is there still a need for the Visistor pattern in a programming language that supports open classes or class extensions?

I'm unsure. It can still be implemented, obviously, but it could also be replaced.

Comment: There is common knowledge, which - if used properly can be used to communicate program intents. I personally dont use funky language features, when using OOP. OOP concepts have their own place, their own sets of rules and own design patterns which are to make things straightforward in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not entirely valid. *Should OOP-principle X be replaced by language feature Y?* actually can never be answered because OOP principles are logically preceding language design questions, which are to a certain extent subject to available technologies, 'zeitgeist' and such things.

Comment: I think the question isn't about replacing as much as continued need. For example, C code obviously can use the Visitor pattern pretty well. But do more advanced languages still have added benefit from the pattern?

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. C# probably not. But programmers in general A LOT. Think e.g. of programmers who try to migrate from Java to C#, and who knows what in 20-30 years will be. As I told, it's not a question of a specific language, but rather about OOP programming as a profession.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

When you have a heterogeneous collection of types in your data model and various kinds of processing you'll need to do to it, the visitor pattern let's you implement each kind of processing separately, without cluttering up the interface of the basic data model classes.

For instance, maybe you need to make a pdf overview, export to a database, save to a file, perform some kind of graph analysis -- in each case examining all of the parts of the data model.  Instead of adding a method to the interface of each element to do each kind of processing you need, the document model simply handles traversal, which gets implemented in only one place.  The visitor is specialized to its process (a database exporter, e.g.) and has methods for processing each type of element.  When a new element-type is added, the compiler forces you not to forget to add it to every visitor/processor.  When a new process is added, it requires no change to the document model classes.

Here's [a very good explanation of the visitor pattern.](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor)
And I found the [wikipedia article on the visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) helpful as well