# Visitor Pattern still useful in languages supporting class extensions?

Tags: visitor-pattern

Is the visitor pattern useful in languages supporting class extensions?

Why bother implementing it, when you have open classes or can subclass.
If you want new functionality for a class you could just subclass it, so unless I'm missing something, is it still (very) useful in languages supporting class extensions?

Comment: What are "open classes"? Can you give an example of a language supporting this? Also, what do you mean by "class extensions"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use/Need of Visitor Pattern in prog. lang. that support class extensions or open classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824091/use-need-of-visitor-pattern-in-prog-lang-that-support-class-extensions-or-open)